# How can Ruby on Rails's "content_for :title" get something that is assigned later?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The short question is: how can a subpage's

```
<% content_for :title do 'Showing product' end %>
```

set the `:title` for the main layout?

---

details:

We can use in the application layout `application.html.erb`

```
<title><%= content_for :title %>
  ...
  <%= yield %>
```

and I think `yield` returns the content for a subpage, such as from `show.html.erb`, where it contains:

```
<% content_for :title do 'Showing product' end %>
```

How can the `:title` somehow get used by something above the `yield`?  I thought the `title` part is evaluated first, and then the `yield`, so how can the `:title` retroactively set the content for the `<title>` tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: By cheating.

Long answer: ActionView redefines yield so it is not the same yield we know and love from good ol' ruby. In fact the template file is rendered before the layout file and then the yield in the layout file will be substituted by the already rendered template. `content_for` blocks are saved into class variables and so you can later access them from your layout.

Answer (score 5):

I defined a helper method `title` in my `application_helper.rb` file like so:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def title(page_title)
    content_for(:title){ page_title }
    page_title
  end
end
```

Then at the top of my content ERB files I can do this

```
<% title "Rails Rocks" %>
Other regular content
```

And in the `application.html.erb`

```
<html>
<head>
  <% title = yield(:title).chop! %>
  <title><%= title || 'Default Title' %></title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="title"><%= title %></h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Why did you put a #chop! there?