# Is it true that Ruby on Rails's "yield" works differently, but all the "render" works like usual?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

this is related to

[How can Ruby on Rails's "content_for :title" get something that is assigned later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118988/how-can-ruby-on-railss-content-for-title-get-something-that-is-assigned-later)

so `yield` is special in Rails, but are all the `render` usual in Rails's controllers and views?  (as in "usual" way of program flow)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, yield is Define in Ruby`s Proc clas.

Assuming to your previous questions, I believe you are refering to content_for from ActionView::Helpers::CaptureHelper.